# Using DialogFragments. Are there bugs in the official example?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I have just copied [the official example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html), and my dialog is very narrow. Why?

[image]

My code.

The dialog.

```
package com.redplanet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener {

    public interface EditNameDialogListener {
        void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText);
    }

    private EditText mEditText;

    public EditNameDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
        getDialog().setTitle("Hello");

        // Show soft keyboard automatically
        mEditText.requestFocus();
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {
            // Return input text to activity
            EditNameDialogListener activity = (EditNameDialogListener) getActivity();
            activity.onFinishEditDialog(mEditText.getText().toString());
            this.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The activity.

```
package com.redplanet;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.redplanet.EditNameDialog.EditNameDialogListener;

public class FragmentDialogDemo extends FragmentActivity implements EditNameDialogListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showEditDialog();
    }

    private void showEditDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        EditNameDialog editNameDialog = new EditNameDialog();
        editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hi, " + inputText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


}
```

Activity layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".FragmentDialogDemo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Dialog layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_your_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_your_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you make any modifications to that code?

Comment: Please post your exact code with it.

Comment: You are creating a Dialog with a layout that is wrap_content, as a layout you can set it to an specific dp or fill_parent/match_parent. It looks like a normal behaviour for me.

Comment: you should try the simpleStyleDialogs. Once you get them running, it saves you alot of time and it looks good by default ;)  https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to puzzle over workarounds, I'd prefer an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) to a `DialogFragment`. The issue I asked about was on Android 2.3.6 and wasn't on Android 4.1.2.